# TinyMCE when copy/pasted from MS Word bullet lists are not converted to OL/UL/LI tags

Tags: javascript, java, tinymce, jsoup, tinymce-4

Covered, as required by the attending physician and when appropriate for your condition.  Services include:
   General ann.
   Regional ann.
   Monitored annwhen you meet data's high-risk criteria.

Comment: Soo, what was your question? I presume that you have a question about code rather than just a manual copy/paste?

Comment: What is the HTML that Word is placing in the clipboard?  If you are on a Mac you can use clipboard viewer to see that.  On Windows I would wager there is a similar tool.